# How to use ultimate thread group in JMeter for below case..?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, threadgroup

I want to run a load test for 350 users on different pages of a application and below is the case i am looking for.
Initially add 50 users, and next need to add 35 users every 60 seconds until it reaches the limit of 350 and the load time should be 15 mins.
Tried with different thread groups but the number of samples are getting more than 350 ( Even when Embedded Resources is not checked )

Answer (score 0):

The setup of the [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) for your scenario would be something like:

[image]

The reason for getting more than 350 sampler results is that you're kicking off 350 **virtual users** which start executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) as fast as they can.

From the above chart by 9th minute of your test you will have 360 users up and running and how many requests do you think they will be able to do in the remaining 5 minutes? I don't know as well, it depends on your application response time but my expectation is that you will get many more than 350 results. See [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second) article for more detailed explanation if needed.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve there should be different options, like if you want to send 350 requests in 15 minutes it means that you need to send 23 requests per minute or roughly 1 request each 3 seconds, it can be easily achieved with 1 thread and [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)